# Python on Embedded

Tags: python, embedded

Есть ли платформа, на которой одновременно можно разработать и протестировать скрипт? Имею ввиду мобильную платформу. Где скрипты могли бы играть роль исполняемых файлов (chmod u+x file.py). И реально ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

- берёте почти любую Embedded Linux платформу
- собраете для неё питон или берёте уже собранный
- Python on Embedded получен

Правда тут один момент.. вы говорите, что надо разрабатывать на этой платформе... Видимо, придётся использовать vim или emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Андроид допускает редактирование и выполнение скриптов на Питоне на телефоне с помощью [Android Scripting Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

Comment: Да, несомненно писать программы в телефоне очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

[Maemo](http://pymaemo.garage.maemo.org/) на Nokia N900